# How to parse url by route to get RouteValues in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I can create url using route. `html.RouteLink("routename",routevalue);`

I need back operation. For example : `html.ParseUrlByRoute("routename",url):routevalues` this must return routevalue.

Or get routename `html.GetRoute(url):string`

Sometimes my web user tell me my web URL. I need get object automatically by the URL.

Is there Any available function?

Or how to do that?

Comment: Sometimes my web user tell me my web URL. I need get object automatically by the URL. - please explain for what do you need it? Maybe it will be easier to help u

Comment: Like facebook. When i add url into facebook comment, facebook recognize url and show web info. I need like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData`. It returns a RouteData Object which contains everything you need.
It accepts an HttpContextBase parameter so you need to create a context based on your url first.

Also if you need to check current route data, the context is already there in the Controller/Page object

Answer (score 0):

use context.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
same for Action and Area
or 
context.RouteData.Datatokens.keys

but accepts an HttpContextBase parameter,so you need to create a context